# ActiveX component can't create object in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8, windows-server-2016

The error is:

```
ActiveX component can't create object for aBRR.Generator
```

The code on that line is:

```
set taMaker = createObject("aBRR.Generator")
```

Classic-asp in the app pool has Enable 32 bit to true.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your website's IUSR account have the relevant permissions on the component dll?

Comment: where would you find the component dll? I don't know classic asp

Comment: I don't know the component, but Program Files (x86) is a good place to look, assuming that it is a 32 bit component.  Have you done a server migration recently?  If so it's possible it hasn't even been installed on the new server

Answer (score 1):

If your site is using Anonymous authentication:

- Open IIS Manager
- Navigate to your site
- Open *Authentication*
- Open the properties for *Anonymous*
- Change it to use *Application Pool Identity*

Note that if your site runs under a special user you created for that purpose, this may break other things. But for all of my standard sites with Anonymous auth, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that there was both a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of regasm.exe.  As in:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe

vs.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe

I also had the AppPool set for 32 bit applications, so it was important that I use the 32bit regasm.exe to register the .dll in order to avoid the ActiveX error.